# Is there a more concise way to write this sql query rather than using sum over and over?

Tags: php, sql

It seems very redundant. What I'm doing is taking the tasks for particular employees and the department they're in and assigning their tasks over the course of two weeks based on when datediff and follow up date are equal assign a 1 which is true and sum the total at the end.

```
$_2weeks = "select
        isnull(b.employee, 'Event Total') as Employee,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))<='-2' then 1 else 0 end) '2+ Days Behind',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='-1' then 1 else 0 end) '1 Day Behind',
        sum(case when cast(a.follow_up as date)=cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end) 'Today<br>&nbsp;" . date('m/d') . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='1' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+1 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='2' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+2 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+2 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='3' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+3 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+3 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='4' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+6 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+6 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='5' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+7 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+7 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='6' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+8 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+8 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='7' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+9 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+9 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='8' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+10 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+10 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='9' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+13 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+13 day')) . "',
        sum(1) AS 'Total'
    from " . event_table('event') . " a
    left outer join " . event_table('employee') . " b on a.employee_id=b.id
    where a.task_id like '%$task_id%'
    and b.department_id like '$dept_id'
    and a.status=1
    and a.task_id<>''
    group by b.employee with rollup";
```

As well as a more concise method for the substr and strtotime php functions? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why too localized?  This pattern occurs very often in reporting applications that use SQL.

Comment: Use a subquery that returns the `datediff` expression. You still have to repeat the `sum` and `case`, but not all the stuff in the datediff.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that a bit Barmar?

Comment: Could you explain the rationale behind the `substr(date(), 0, 1)` (sometimes it's `0,2`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could expand the `group by` to include the day difference.  For example:

```
select  b.employee
,       datediff(dd,cast(getdate() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date)) as DaysInPast
,       count(a.task_id) as TaskCount
group by
        b.employee
,       datediff(dd,cast(getdate() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))
```

You'd have to generate the column names client side, and possibly pivot the results.  In the end, that might be more complex (certainly in terms of lines of code) than your current solution.

Comment: This might be a great option. Thank you.

Comment: what do i do with the sum function?

Comment: You can use `count` instead of `sum`, since the group is already limited to one specific day

Comment: Can you briefly explain the "generate the column names client side and "pivoting results"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run both queries and compare the result.  You'll see how it differs from the original.  As the last line of the answer says, making the SQL query simpler will make the PHP code more complex.

Answer (score 0):

. . If you just need to avoid the "visual problem" of this repetition, you can create a php function to output the correct string, like...

```
    function sqlline($i, $n) {
        $timestr = strtotime('+'. $i .' day');
        $d = date('l/m/d', $timestr);
        $d2 = date('m/d', $timestr);

        return 'SUM '.
            '(CASE WHEN '.
                'DATEDIFF (dd, cast(GETDATE() as date), cast(a.follow_up as date)) = "'. $i .'" '.
            'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '.
            '"'. substr($d, 0, $n) .'<br>'. $d2 .
            ', '
    }
```

. . And call it with `sqlline(1, 1) . sqlline(2, 1) (...)`.

. . But I think you should really think a little bit more about the goal of the code and how some of this could be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily what you ask (simplify the PHP part), but I think you could reduce the "visual clutter" of your SQL code if your database supports sub-tables like this:

```
select
        isnull(b.employee, 'Event Total') as Employee,
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff<='-2' then 1 else 0 end) '2+ Days Behind',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='-1' then 1 else 0 end) '1 Day Behind',
        sum(case when cast(a.follow_up as date)=cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end) 'Today<br>&nbsp;" . date('m/d') . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='1' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+1 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='2' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+2 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+2 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='3' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+3 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+3 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='4' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+6 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+6 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='5' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+7 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+7 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='6' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+8 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+8 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='7' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+9 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+9 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='8' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+10 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+10 day')) . "',
        sum(case when sub.dat_diff='9' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+13 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+13 day')) . "',
        sum(1) AS 'Total'
FROM (
SELECT a.employee_id, a.task_id, DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date)) as dat_diff
FROM " . event_table('event') . " a
WHERE a.status=1
) sub
LEFT JOIN ... (etc.)
```

Also, you should probably avoid calling "getdate" so many times - most probably calling it once, storing the value in a variable and pasting it within the code would be enough and slightly faster.

My 2 cents ;)